# Algorithm for creating a AutoScheduling app

Tags: algorithm, sorting, artificial-intelligence

I am a beginner in React and decided to start with this project.

Essentially I am trying to make an Auto scheduler, which takes tasks, which are essentially object with properties like due-date, importance, subject, topic etc.

So I am trying to develop an algorithm where it takes in an array of these task object and sorts them to fit the schedule. My problem is how do I go about creating a complex algorithm like this, and sort the list.

Lets also assume that I were to add global rules such as I dont do more than 8 hours of hw a day, or I dont do two hws for the same class in a row.

How can I go about developing such an Algorithm?

Here was my idea. (I havent implemented this yet) I essentially develop an equation, where I multiply all of task object properties with a constant, and give them a sorting number, and then sort the array by that number.

Finally I run a loop on this array, and make sure that the global rules are met.

If you have a better idea or solution please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot of scheduling research you should look into. Most of these problems are among the hardest problems known: just start by looking into job-shop scheduling. It's relatively simple in it's statement and yet there are decade old unsolved instances. I recommend not creating something without getting a feel about the research (huge field). For a lot of those problems we can prove, that your approach can be arbitrarily bad (just by categorizing it as polynomial algorithm; if P!=NP). Constraint-programming, Integer-programming and (Meta-)heuristics are the core of most scheduling solvers

Comment: After some basic research, if still motivated, i recommend playing around with google's ortools (CP / SAT hybrid) or maybe gecode (pure CP; very well documented; but mostly C++ only)

Comment: sascha, thanks very much, I feel like I can do some research on metaheuristics and combinatoric optimization. I have a decent background in math, so hopefully i can develop a solution with this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to throw your process up on the cloud, so you have the benefits of fault tolerance, parallel processing, etc., etc.  Here is one option.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler

```
 Console

    Visit the Cloud Scheduler console page.

    Go to Cloud Scheduler

    Click Create job.

    screenshot

    Supply a name for the job.

    Specify the frequency, or job interval, at which the job is to run, using a configuration string. For example, the string 0 */3 * * * runs the job every 3 hours. The string you supply here can be any crontab compatible string.

    For more information, see Configuring Job Schedules.

    From the dropdown list, choose the timezone to be used for the job frequency.

    Specify HTTP as the target:

        Specify the fully qualified URL of your service, for example https://myservice-abcdef-uc.a.run.app The job will send requests to this URL.

        Specify the HTTP method: the method must match what your previously deployed Cloud Run service is expecting. The default is POST.

        Optionally, specify the data to be sent to the target. This data is sent in the body of the request when either the POST or PUT HTTP method is selected.

        Click More to show the auth settings.

        From the dropdown menu, select Add OIDC token.

        In the Service account field, copy the service account email of the service account you created previously.

        In the Audience field, copy the full URL of your service.

    Click Create to create and save the job.

Gcloud

    Create the job:

    gcloud beta scheduler jobs create http test-job --schedule "5 * * * *" \
       --http-method=HTTP-METHOD \
       --uri=SERVICE-URL \
       --oidc-service-account-email=SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL   \
       --oidc-token-audience=SERVICE-URL

Replace

    HTTP-METHOD with the HTTP method, eg, GET, POST, PUT, etc.
    SERVICE-URL with your service URL.
    SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL with your service account email.
```

Also, and this is kind of the old-fashioned way of doing it, but I grew up in the 80s and early 90s, so I'm still a fan of Windows Scheduler.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10

[image]